# Swift Ios setting delegate without self as other view controller

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, segue, viewcontroller

I have seen everywhere that delegate variable is always set to self.

```
thirdClass.delegate = self
```

So i want something like

```
thirdViewController.delegate = firstViewControllerToDo
```

In my case,

```
let thirdClassVar = thirdClass()
thirdClassVar.namVar = "somnam"
thirdClassVar.delegate = firstViewControllerToDo
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gtoFirstViewcontroller", sender: self)
```

When i click on button in second screen, it wil return back to first screen but in background I want to do some calculation in thirdClass and after completion of that, it shud display a message in first screen.

How can i achieve this or is there any other way of getting this done.

Comment: add another delegate, or rethink how your app is designed

Answer (score 0):

You want doing something but you do something with wrong way. I think you can do this process with UIButton and IBAction functions, change your algorith for this process.